# How to analyse StackOverflow Q&A for root cause analysis if it expected in the problem?

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, data-science

Most of the questions on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com) are about how to do it? Like the question for which solution is sought or this one ([How to get cpu-id in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2206712/how-to-get-cpu-id-in-java)) but some of them actually ask to cause of the problem for example ([Why does this fail without static_cast?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2483260/why-does-this-fail-without-static-cast)) or ([Why do I get a PHPDoc warning in PhpStorm over this code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9823085/why-do-i-get-a-phpdoc-warning-in-phpstorm-over-this-code)) that does not necessarily mean it has to be **why** question but the intent is asking for the reason behind the problem.

I want to get the root cause of the problem if it is expected (such as in why questions) and its solution, otherwise for how and what questions- just pick the accepted solution or most-voted ones.

How do you prepare a dataset for such task and how to solve it? I am looking for an idea. A preliminary approach will suffice to proceed. For my background, I have worked on sentiment analysis (using BOW method though), sequential network and have an idea about the latest NLP [Transformers](https://ai.googleblog.com/2017/08/transformer-novel-neural-network.html) model.

Comment: Welcome to SO, which is about *specific coding* questions, and not a tutorial, design, recommendation, or discussion forum; your question is way too broad, please do take some time to read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @desertnaut I agree that my question is a bit more general than it forum permits but It is also specific in regard to how do you get the intent from text. Like is it just asking information or the reason for the problem?

Comment: Please notice that *specific* is a necessary condition but not sufficient in itself, and SO is about *specific coding* questions.

Comment: @desertnaut Thank you for the tip. I looked at your profile which seem pretty accomplished in Data Science maybe please you can help me here or direct me where to discuss such problems.